# Can I connect two subnetworks in two diferent projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have two projects on Google Cloud Compute Engine, with two different networks and subnetworks.

Project A - Network A - Subnetwork A
Project B - Network B - Subnetwork B

How can I connect Subnetwork A to with Subnetwork B? I want to my servers can reach each other. So a server in Subnetwork A can communicate to a server in B, and vice versa. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a VPN tunnel between the two networks in your projects. You can have more information about Google Cloud VPN in this Help Center [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/creating-vpns).